# why I got error from report server by passing date/time object to datetime variable in stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, reporting-services, rdl

In my project, I am using reporting service to create report form SQL DB.
However, the error below is shown (ALL variable which of type datetime bring this error).

> The value provided for the report parameter 'THE_DATE' is not
>   valid for its type.

I will tell you all the information I can provided to you for this question.

In report project,

1. I build up a field which its f(x) is `=IIf
   (Parameters!THE_DATE.Value Is
   Nothing,Nothing,Format(Parameters!THE_DATE.Value,"yyyy-MM-dd"))`
2. I also create a variable named `THE_DATE` which of type Date/Time and set Allow null value.
3. In the dataset, the query is

> ```
>  EXEC MC_GetDateReport @THE_DATE,  @DEPARTMENT,
>  @TYPE, @ID
> ```

In the SQL:
the stored procedure is shown as below:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[MC_GetDateReport ] 
    @THE_DATE as datetime = null,
    @DEPARTMENT as nvarchar(MAX) = null,
    @TYPE as nvarchar(MAX) = null,
    @LAN_ID as nvarchar(MAX) = null
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE
    @SQLSTRING nvarchar(MAX),
    @PARAMETER nvarchar(500);
    SET @CASE = 0;
    SELECT @SQLSTRING = N'';
```

Could anyone tell me why it say The 'THE_DATE' is not valid as both variable is type of datetime?

Comment: What is the date that you are passing ? I just want to know the format of date.

Comment: Might be region settings or a difference between sql and ssrs date for mats.

Comment: @AjayPrajapati in the input field, I enter `21/02/2017` by clicking its calendar selector (build-in). it will bring error. but I enter `21-02-2017` directly without the calendar selector, it will be fine.

Comment: Here is the problem, the date format in SQL is MM/dd/yyyy. Pass your date as 02/21/2017 , it will work.